# Convert Oracle decode statement into SQL Server T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, decode

whe no longer will be using oracle database, our focus is convert all query statement from Oracle to a SQL Server (T-SQL) Statement. I been having some issues when it comes down with Decode, the following line I been trying to change it but it give me some error when I run it in sql server for testing.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT DocType, 
docyear, 
docmonth, 
DECODE(docmonth, NULL, NULL, '0', '- All Months -', TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(docmonth||'/01/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'docmonth')) 
monthAlpha, 
DID 
from dbo.Document where XALASKAID = '" & LicenseNumber & "' and DOCTYPE like '%Report%'"
```

But this decode line , is causing an error.

Comment: "our focus is convert all query statement from oracle to sql statement" .... Oracle uses SQL statements! What do you mean by this as it does not make sense?

Comment: "some error" - care to share?

Comment: So you are calling the query from VBA? What error are you having?

Comment: Are you getting an error on DECODE because you're using SQL Server (guessing by the DBO schema) and DECODE doesn't exist in SQL Server?

Comment: There is no valid SQL statement in your question. If you have a SQL question, don't obfuscate your SQL statements inside the code of your programming language. Also Oracle uses SQL as its query language so you don't need to convert anything

Comment: `'docmonth'` is a strange format for `TO_CHAR` ;-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - On the contrary, he has a lot of work converting Oracle SQL dialect to SQL Server dialect and it can be very painful since many Oracle's features are not supported by SQL Server.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: the question is "*from oracle to sql statement*". Oracle uses SQL so any query that runs in Oracle **is** already a "SQL statement" (unless it's PL/SQL of course)

Comment: I apologies from my confusion: I mean't oracle statement to sql server statement, I read some place about replacing Decode for Case, When and then. but not sure how to apply it to this line:   


DECODE(docmonth, NULL, NULL, '0', '- All Months -', TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(docmonth||'/01/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'docmonth'))

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is standard SQL and available in both Oracle and SQL Server. `DECODE` is Oracle only. It is easy to convert; just read the docs. However, as mentioned, TO_CHAR's second parameter is a format, e.g. 'MM/DD/YYYY' for dates, but in your code it is 'docmonth' which doesn't make sense.

Comment: let me clear a little bit more.  I have a column in the table that is call `docmonth` which save a number from 0-12. from those number I want to convert it to the actual word: example `case docmonth when 1 then January` ... it works like this and I can do it, but it will be so long query statement, so Im trying to make a `To_CHAR(To_DATE` to grab that number and represent it as month in word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try a CASE statement instead?

```
Dim query As String = "
SELECT
docType, 
docyear, 
docmonth, 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(docmonth||'/01/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'docmonth')) 
CASE
  WHEN docmonth IS NULL THEN NULL
  WHEN docmonth = '0' THEN '- All Months -'
  WHEN docmonth >= AND docmonth <= 12 THEN DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, docmonth, -1))
END CaseDocMonth,
monthAlpha, 
DID 
FROM dbo.Document
WHERE XALASKAID = '" & LicenseNumber & "'
AND DOCTYPE like '%Report%';"
```

I've [written about DECODE before](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-decode-function/), and CASE is generally preferred anyway, because it's easier to read, and has more flexibility.

Comment: The rest works fine but

MS SQL doesn't understand: 

`TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(docmonth||'/01/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'docmonth')) `

I just have values from 0 - 12 in the column, and trying to show it in wording(months word) instead of numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Those two functions are Oracle-specific as well. I've read your other comments about getting the month name, and I think the DATENAME function should do the trick. I've updated my answer. I don't have access to SQL Server right now, but let me know if there are any issues with this query.

Comment: Thank for the modifications, you awesome it works!!!!, your code helped me a lot to convert.
my end script is now:
`Dim query As String = "SELECT DocType, docyear, CASE WHEN docmonth IS NULL THEN NULL " & _
            "WHEN docmonth = '0' THEN '- All Months -' WHEN docmonth >= 1 AND docmonth <= 12 " & _
            "THEN DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, docmonth, -1)) END DocMonth, DID from dbo.Document where XALASKAID = '" & LicenseNumber & "' and DOCTYPE like '%Report%'"`

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

Using Oracle's proprietary functions (**DECODE**, **TO_CHAR** and **TO_DATE**) or even the concatenation operator (**||**) in SQL Server won't get you far.

## 2.

`case ... when null` won't work.

e.g.

```
declare @t table (i int)
insert into @t (i) values (null)
select case i when null then 1 else 2 end as x from @t
```

---

```
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

instead of

```
case x when null then ... when y then ... when z then .. else ... end
```

You'll have to use

```
case when x is null then ... when x = y then ... when x = z then ... else ... end
```